# Vapor barrier plastic sheathing on wrong side of wall?

Tags: drywall, insulation

I recently torn down some drywall in my garage and noticed the plastic sheathing was on the wall on the garage side (other side of the wall is the family room), when I thought the sheathing should be on the inside? Without doing any drywall removal on the inside, can I fix the problem with putting faced insulation where the face is touching the family room wall and staple the paper to the inside studs? Or what is the correct way to fix this problem? I don't have any visible damage, but just want to fix it the correct way since the wall is removed (and the plastic was damaged removing the drywall).

Comment: Is garage heated/condition or unheated?  Do you have winter like temperatures(f-ing cold)?  Proper way is vapour barrier(plastic or faced insulation) on heated wall, then insulation, then outside sliding.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for the response. The garage is not heated but the adjacent family room on the other side of the wall is. Without, ripping out the entire interior wall as well, can I just install new faced insulation and staple the sides to the 2x4s?

Comment: To add, yes F-ing cold winters. haha

Comment: Yes, have the face towards heated side or can replace plastic vapour barrier, harder to do right, since you would need to around the studs, then add unfaced insulation. Do think it does cut on drafts better than faced insulation.